# Getting error while running migration command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The message I'm getting after running migration command 
[image]

The db file created after runnig above command is as below

[enter image description here][2]

Error I'm getting while trying to connect with table(demo) in database demo:

[image]

Comment: Please post your migration file code and error message

Answer (score 1):

let me explain about your error message and your understanding above, when you typed rails generate migration demo (this is from your picture) and then the command line showing the file created, it does not meant the db file created, rails generate migration command usually to add/remove fields from existing table, it's just empty file that that you should put some additional command inside, check db/migration folder,

I believe this [getting started with rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) can help you.

#### basically for database steps

- Create database file first with **rake db:create**
- create your model with **rails generate model Demo**, again file created but you have to put some fields inside, check db/migration folder after you run this command
- after you put fields then run **rake db:migrate**
- if you missed some fields then you can add additional fields with **rails generate migration AddDateToDemo**
- then put some fields inside and then run **rake db:migrate**, it's script for rails to execute job database creation/add/remove fields